# How does geometrixx outdoor's Order page work in AEM 6?

Tags: aem

in AEM, how does geometrixx-outdoor's Orders.html page work.

```
http://localhost:4502/aem/orders.html/etc/commerce/orders
```

my initial finding is that `/libs/commerce/gui/content/orders` is being rendered and data is fetched from `/etc/commerce/orders` folder. but i'm not able to figure out how it's fetching data for the users. i need to extend this functionality and check if i can use it for the functionality i need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm posting an answer to my own question so that anyone in future might be able to find the post a bit helpful.

Resource Merger API of AEM can be used to extend admin pages in Adobe Experience Manager.
`http://dev.day.com/content/ddc/en/gems/user-interface-customization-for-aem-6.html` first 20 minutes of this screencast explains it really well.
more information about it is given at `https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/using/extending-aem-6-administrator-user.html`

in short, if one wants to add a nav bar entry in AEM, create a node after `/apps/cq/core/content/nav`. your node will be merged with `/libs/cq/core/content/nav entries`.

for creating your own pages in user interface, refer to `/libs/commerce/gui/content/orders` and create only the order node in libs folder(having a resource type `granite/ui/components/foundation/page`). main thing here is that the id in order node here should match the id given in nav bar node above. `/libs/cq/gui/components/siteadmin/admin/pages/pages.jsp` is the actual page which resolves the nodes to make header and body of pages.
explore the orders node to know more about how pages are created by adding  only nodes.